# How to check for "method group" via "sender" object?

Tags: c#, winforms, sender, eventargs, method-group

Imagine a method like this ( in Win Forms):

```
//First method
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       //I call another method here
       this.GetData(sender, null)
}

//Second method
private void GetData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       //how to check IF calling method is buttonStart_Click ???
       if(sender.Equals == buttonStart_Click) 
       {
            //DO BLAH BLAH
       }
}
```

I hope I was clear, that is I want to know which method is calling 'GetData'. **note** I know I can have a global variable and set it to something, but I want to know if there is a DIRECT way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? There are probably better ways to do this.

Comment: If you are using WPF, you can use command with command parameter.

Comment: I want to know what methods has called another method, whithout using extra arguments. And it is in WinForms.

Comment: Why do you need to know who called that method? That's supposed to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sender` is not going to be `buttonStart_Click`, it will simply be the button. So you can test for it.

```
if (sender != null && sender.Equals(buttonStart))
{
   // work with this information
}
```

However, if you find yourself going down this route, you may end up seeing multiple `if` blocks each with different behaviors depending on the identity of `sender`. If that is the case, you'd be better served with a different approach. Have a different handler for each event, encapsulate the differing logic via a delegate, etc. Do not end up with a page full of `if / else if / else if / ...`.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind giving a delegate example for this case?

Comment: @Sean, nothing that isn't purely contrived. The point I'm making is to be sure about your approach and investigate alternatives. You want to avoid ending up with a kitchen-sink method that is doing way too much and making decisions that are only tangentially related. Maybe all you need to do is pass in a parameter, maybe `buttonStart_Click` actually needs to do work rather than letting `GetData` handle everything, or maybe `buttonStart_Click` needs to give `GetData` the means to do what it needs to do without `GetData` knowing what those means are (e.g, a delegate).

Comment: (And this delegate could in fact be an `Action<>` or `Func<>`.) Here's a suggestion. Continue working on whatever you're doing. Once you have more code, perhaps ask a new question about how you can refactor it into something more manageable (if warranted).

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do something different because you called the method from some other method, it's probably best to just call a different method:

```
//First method
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       //I call another method here
       this.SpecialGetData(sender, null)
}

//Second method
private void GetData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Do regular stuff
}

//Special second method
private void SpecialGetData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //DO BLAH BLAH
}
```

Comment: hmm the problem is 'if(sender.Equals == buttonStart_Click) ' is not compilable

Comment: @Sean: sorry, forgot to remove that. Fixed it.

Comment: Yeah I know it is possible like this, but I dont know if this is a DIRECT way of doing this tast, then somone may endup with thousand methods. How to do it inside one method?

Comment: @Sean87: in the general case **you can't know** what method called you. The JIT is free to do optimizations like inlining method calls.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you do this way, but if you need...
http://www.csharp411.com/c-get-calling-method/

Comment: And please that into consideration the following sentence from the documentation: "StackTrace might not report as many method calls as expected, due to code transformations that occur during optimization."